# How can I measure amplitude of a photon and an electron wave?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves

I want to know how is amplitude measured for a photon and an electron wave
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by the amplitude of a photon or an electron? Are you talking about the amplitude of their wave function at some value, are you thinking of them as waves and asking about the amplitude of that wave? There isn't enough clarity to answer this question meaningfully. Voting to close for now.

Answer (score 3):

In [mainstream physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model), both the photon and the electron are point particles. The photon does not have an amplitude. It has energy $E=hν$ where $ν$ is the frequency of the classical electromagnetic wave built up by a large number of photons.

See how in the [double slit experiment](https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/) one photon at a time, the points accumulating show  the interference pattern of the classical wave.

[image: photdb]

> Figure 1. Single-photon camera recording of photons from a double slit illuminated by very weak laser light. Left to right: single frame, superposition of 200, 1’000, and 500’000 frames

The random points on the left are photon footprints. The interference pattern on the right analyzed will give the frequency and thus measure the energy of the photon.

[The similar experiment one electron at a time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles), shows the footprint of the electron , and the accumulation shows that the wave nature of the electron is in the probability space, as seen by the interference pattern that appears when adding up many same momentum electrons.

[image: electrdbl]

> Buildup of interference pattern from individual particle detections

This is the way to measure the wave nature of the probability of measuring an electron (which is a point particle as seen when falling on the slits one at a time).

Comment: Really nice answer.